# Flutter support rtl

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am starting to work on one big project, So my question is can I change the direction of the listview to RTL,

```
new ListTile(
      trailing: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      onTap: onTab,
      leading: new Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: new Text("Test"),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify the direction for any subtree of the UI:

```
new Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, 
    child: new ListTile(...))
```

See also https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. It works. ^_^

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Link not exists!